# How to trace session creation

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, servlets

greetings all
i have an application which are made with Spring framework and deployed on apache,tomcat
and i see on tomcat manager that there are many un-used sessions in the application
and i want to trace when this session are created and who is creating them, how to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `HttpSessionListener`, register it in web.xml (or with annotations, if using servlet 3.0).

the `sessionCreated(..)` method is triggered whenever a session is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could install either LambdaProbe or it's fork [PSIProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) which will give you details such as this. Both are open source products and usage is very similar to the Tomcat Manager.

LambdaProbe does not seem to be maintained any more. 
But see the session list screenshot for PSIProbe, you can see the Age and IP of each session.

http://psi-probe.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/Features/session-list.png