# Listening for Hibernate Session creation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, trace

I have a bug in my code that is causing a hibernate exception where an object is being associated with two open sessions when calling `session.lock()`.

I am using Spring 3.0.4 with HibernateTemplate and Hibernate 3.6.0.

I would like to be able to trap when a Session is created, create/store a stacktrace for the Session and then proxy the Session so when `close()` is called the the stacktrace is cleaned up.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959035/how-to-trace-session-creation) but this is specifically for web-apps.  I've poked through the hibernate event/Session factory stats code and spring code but can't see an appropriate hook point.

Does anyone have any suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to debug / troubleshoot the problem you are facing - enabling debug logging for spring hibernate is a simpler / better option.  You will be able to trace where the second session is opened.

Comment: Unfortunately my app has a lot of querying going on in different threads so the logging situation can be quite confused when trying to track down an issue of this nature.